# How in Delphi to make the frame completely overlap the form on which it is located (given the fact that the form can be scrolled)?

Tags: delphi

There are several frames in my application. All of them are located on the form - on the main. In some frames, the height can be very large, so it should be possible to scroll the form on which such frames are located. I set the `autoscroll` flag to `true` for the main form, on which all the frames are located. And wrote the following code - so that the height and width of the frames correspond to the form.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Unit3;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Frame31: TFrame3;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetPosition;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetPosition;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetPosition;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetPosition;
begin
  Frame31.Left := 0;
  Frame31.Top := 0;
  Frame31.Width := Form1.Width;
  Frame31.Height := Form1.Height;
end;

end.
```

Here is the code for one of the frames.

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TFrame3 = class(TFrame)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Besides the frames on the main form, I have some other elements. And if you scroll, the frames are smaller than the form. I made a screenshot, look, please. Red is a frame. And gray is a form. Why the form sticks out from under the frame? How to make it (frame) completely overlap the form? And if the information does not fit on the frame, the form can be scrolled.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: "*[I] wrote the following code - so that the height and width of the frames correspond to the form*" - there is no such code shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank. I have corrected

Comment: try using the Form's `ClientWidth`/`ClientHeight` properties instead of the `Width`/`Height` properties.

Comment: What about `Frame31.Align := alClient`?

Comment: @DelphiCoder, this does not work

Comment: Can you please give more details. What exactly is not working?

Comment: And I think you have to the set the ´AutoScroll´ property of the frame(s).